# PHP best way to import and store data from configuration file

Tags: php, json

Dears, one doubt I´m upgrading an old project but was required the possibilities of import values of configuration like, database, api url, api ports etcs, and store that values in PHP for be used in various classes.

I  tryied to search a best way to do that,

I'm considering store in static variables, anyone have best idea please.

actually the file have this values:

```
{
"type_db": "mysql",
"name_db": "sysbase",
"host_db": "159.120.010.100",
"port_db": "3306",
"username": "dev_056",
"password": "ZmFzdDkwMDI="
```

}

Comment: You're going to want to change that mysql password there, bud.

Comment: That said, there is no general "best" for this. Everyone is going to have their own opinion, and it's highly dependent on your existing codebase, requirements, and opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Store it in JSON format in a standard text file. Looks like your attached file is almost in that format. Doesn't need to be more complicated.

[Use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) `json_encode()` on your configurations array and write it to a file

[Use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) `json_decode()` when you read the file and want to convert it back to an array

That should be all you need really.

Also you shouldn't paste passwords and IP addresses into the open like that, as it may expose them to be attacked. You should change them to keep it safe.

Answer (score -1):

Why not make a config.ini file and use parse-ini-file function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Exactly why you no longer use steam-powered cars that cannot go faster than 40 km/h on public roads. It's simply a really old piece of tech and better solutions exist.